# Android: data on status bar

Tags: android, statusbar

I want to develop an application that shows data in the status bar, for example the current internet speed. I want to update it every second.

I was trying to use Notifications, but i couldnt find a way to show numbers without an icon and to update it.

is it possible to do what i want? How can i achieve it? Which class shoud i use?
Do you hace a source code example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to do what i want?

Not from an Android SDK application. A custom Android OS build could do that. The only way an SDK application can affect the status or system bars is by means of a `Notification`.

Answer (score 0):

That is possible.I've been doing that. Use updown meter free from android market. But the problem with that software is that it will drain your battery.